# cannot resolve symbol textView - Android Studio

Tags: java, android

XML part:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
        android:text="4"
        android:textSize="90sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

METHOD :

```
public void tapButton(View view) {

        String str = " Hello";
        textView.text = str;
    }
```

I saw a few answers but they didnt help out...i need help!!

Comment: What is textView?

Comment: I have just started but asper i know it is used to display text on app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare and initialize the variable `textView`:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(....);
```

Comment: didnt work...TextView and setText cannot be resoloved

Answer (score 0):

Did you import TextView? If not, add it like this:

```
import android.widget.TextView;
```

Comment: i did but it import word gets black...so i guess its a problem with it and textview in import also says cannot resolve symbol

Comment: Importing a type doesn't mean that it will be auto initialized. Make your grounds clear before giving a lecture on how jvm optimizes stuff. Owning a youtube channel doesn't mean you know stuff.